# Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Filter: Generic HTTP requests not allowed

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I am getting this message "Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Filter: Generic HTTP requests not allowed" on browser while hitting local request from local (https://localhost:8443)
    My question is, if set cors.allowGenericHttpRequests init param value "false" then showing above message"Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Filter: Generic HTTP requests not allowed" on browser if set it true then it working for all orgins(localhost:8443, 192.168.x.x:8443) request that it should not work for this orgin "https://192.168.x.x:8443" request .

Below is my web.xml file

```
    <servlet>
                <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
                <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
            </servlet>
            <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
            </servlet-mapping>
             <filter>
                <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
                <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
                <init-param>
                    <param-name>cors.allowGenericHttpRequests</param-name>
                    <param-value>false</param-value>
                </init-param>
                <init-param>
                    <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
                    <param-value>https://localhost:8443 http://localhost:8080/</param-value>
                </init-param>
                <init-param>
                    <param-name>cors.allowSubdomains</param-name>
                    <param-value>true</param-value>``
                </init-param>

                <init-param>
                    <param-name>cors.tagRequests</param-name>
                    <param-value>true</param-value>
                </init-param>
                <init-param>
                    <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
                    <param-value>GET, POST, PUT, DELETE</param-value>
                </init-param>
                <init-param>
                    <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
                    <param-value>*</param-value>
                </init-param>
                <init-param>
                    <param-name>cors.exposedHeaders</param-name>
                    <param-value>X-Test-1, X-Test-2</param-value>
                </init-param>
                <init-param>
                    <param-name>cors.supportsCredentials</param-name>
                    <param-value>true</param-value>
                </init-param>

                <init-param>
                    <param-name>cors.maxAge</param-name>
                    <param-value>3600</param-value>
                </init-param>
            </filter>
            <filter-mapping>
                <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            </filter-mapping>
```